# Winform: SplitterContainer inside a SplitterContainer misbehaves

Tags: c#, panel, splitter

I have a splittercontainer (vertical) placed on form.  In the right panel, I placed another splittercontainer (horizontal).

When I run the application, the topmost splittercontainer works fine, no issues.  The problem is with the embedded splittercontainer.

The size of the embedded splittercontainer when resized is fine, however the panels show up as a smaller size.  I did not even thing that was possible.  I cannot seem to get the embedded panel to consistently show the proper dimensions.

I did a search, and turned up this article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953934

I tried out the recommended solution, and quite usual for any Microsoft post, it does not work.

In fact, things worked better without the suggested solution.  At least after the application showed, I was able to get the panels to size properly, just by adjusting the splitter container of either control.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Sarah

Comment: That KB article is not close to your problem, you'd have to nest many hundreds of splitters.  Post code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suffering for quite some time, it seems that posting my question got my head to think of a solution.

The outer splittercontainer must be set for docking type fill.  Embed the second splitter container directly inside Panel 2 and have that set to docking type fill.

In the resize event, do not add any Controls.Add() for the splitter container, as that is done in the designer.  You should add a Controls.Add() for any forms that you want to show.

Do not size the splittercontainers.  Allow Windows to do that.  Do resize the forms.  Make sure to set the TopLevel to false first and show the form after adding to the control of the panel.

I tried the docking type none and several other things.  It was either setting to none or setting the manually setting the sizing or whatever that caused the problem.

I hope this post helps someone.